# Single Cycle Data-path Requirements

Tags: computer-architecture

How does having separate instruction and data memories help in implementing a single cycle datapath for a MIPS instruction set? I want to know why we can only use a datapath element once in a cycle for making the datapath capable of executing any instruction in a single cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Each element in that data path is purely logical, thus in each cycle an element can perform only a single operation.
If you had only one memory element, you would've possibly need to perform two operations in one cycle: (1) read the instruction (2) read/write data. This is impossible with a logic-only (sateless) elements within a single cycle.

Comment: i think memory is a state element